# Syntax for multiple aggregations and column renaming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Would someone be so kind to explain why this agg() is not working for me:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["alice","bob","charlene","alice","bob","charlene","alice","bob","charlene","edna" ],
                   'date':["2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-01"],
                   'contribution': [5,5,10,20,30,1,5,5,10,100],
                   'payment-type': ["cash","transfer","cash","transfer","cash","transfer","cash","transfer","cash","transfer",]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

daily_count = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D')).agg({'name': 'value_counts', 'contribution': 'sum'}).rename(columns={'name': 'name_count', 'contribution': 'contribution_sum' }).reset_index()
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrew/git-analysis/some_pandas_test copy.py", line 11, in <module>
    daily_count = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D')).agg({'name': ['value_counts'], 'contribution': ['sum']}).rename(columns={'name': 'name_count', 'contribution': 'contribution_sum' })
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 928, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 443, in _aggregate
    return concat([result[k] for k in keys], keys=keys, axis=1), True
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 271, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 515, in _get_new_axes
    return [
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 516, in <listcomp>
    self._get_concat_axis() if i == self.axis else self._get_comb_axis(i)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 522, in _get_comb_axis
    return get_objs_combined_axis(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py", line 90, in get_objs_combined_axis
    return _get_combined_index(obs_idxes, intersect=intersect, sort=sort)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py", line 138, in _get_combined_index
    index = union_indexes(indexes, sort=sort)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py", line 205, in union_indexes
    result = result.union(other)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 3211, in union
    uniq_tuples = lib.fast_unique_multiple(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 229, in pandas._libs.lib.fast_unique_multiple
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer
```

If someone is aware of a good agg() cookbook I would be very glad to see it. I am finding it difficult to get to grips with this function.

Ta, Andrew

Comment: `value_counts` returns a series, `sum` returns a number. I believe Pandas has a hard time aligning them.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you intend:

```
>>> (df
     .groupby(df['date'])
     .agg({'name': 'count', 'contribution': np.sum})
     .rename(columns={'name': 'name_count', 'contribution': 'contribution_sum' })
     .reset_index())
        date  name_count  contribution_sum
0 2020-01-01           8               176
1 2020-01-02           2                15
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the section on aggregation in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html? It helped me a lot when I first learned about that stuff.

Concerning your error you can look at the two aggregations seperately

```
In [6]: df.resample('1D', on='date')['name'].value_counts()
Out[6]: 
date        name    
2020-01-01  bob         3
            alice       2
            charlene    2
            edna        1
2020-01-02  alice       1
            charlene    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
In [7]: df.resample('1D', on='date')['contribution'].sum()
Out[7]: 
date
2020-01-01    176
2020-01-02     15
Freq: D, Name: contribution, dtype: int64
```

If all you do is grouping by a frequence in a date column, the `resample` function is simpler than using a `Grouper`. I only use the later in case I want to group by something and resample at the same time.

As you see (and was mentioned in a comment) `value_counts` returns a series with a MultiIndex of `date` and `name` while `sum` returns a series with only `date` as index.

`agg` is roughly a short notation to perform multiple aggregations and concatenate the results to a Dataframe with one column for each result. Because the indices do not match, the two results cannot be combined.
If I try your code on pandas 1.1 I actually get a

```
NotImplementedError: Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead.
```

which basically says there is no way to concatenate Series with different numbers of index levels.